# How to maximize QWidget at startup

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

how to start a widget in fullscreen by default? Tried to add setWindowState but fail.

here is the code:

```
class Main (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        #error: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'setWindowState'
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_clicked)
        self.ui.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_clicked)


    def btn1_clicked(self):
        global value1
        value1 += 1
        self.ui.num1.setText("%d" %value1)

    def btn2_clicked(self):
        global value2
        value2 += 1
        self.ui.num2.setText("%d" %value2)
```

Comment: try using showMaximized()

Comment: @ YTL4110 : added it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `QWidget::showMaximized()` on the parent widget to maximize the window.